# How do I delete the generated function from accidentally double clicking on a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a forms application with a button. When I double click on it on the designer form, it automatically creates a  private void saveButton_Click() function.

How do I delete this function without generating errors in Visual Studio 2012? If I delete the method, it will create an error that states "File does not contain a definition for saveButton_click() and no extension method 'save_button_click'. So how would I delete this method completely as I accidentally created this when I double clicked on the button on designer form?

I can't undo as I have done other changes before trying to fix this. Should I delete something from another file in Visual Studio 2012?

EDIT: I cannot undo (CTRL - Z) as I have saved the files and done other changes as stated above. What I am looking for is a way for Visual Studio to remove all event handlers of when the button is double clicked automatically.

Answer (score 7):

You see this error message, because Visual Studio adds two things when you are double-clicking button:

1) It creates empty event handler in code file

```
void saveButton_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

2) In designer generated code file it subscribes this handler to button click event

```
saveButton.Click += new EventHandler(saveButton_click);
```

When you remove handler, you still have it referenced in designer file. And compiler can't find `saveButton_click` method which you just removed.

If accidental button click is the only change you made, then just click `Ctrl-Z` and operation will be reverted (both handler and event subscription will be removed). In this case you will see this dialog box, don't afraid to click *Yes*

[image]

Otherwise you should remove subscription (either manually, by editing designer file, or [from designer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2751793/470005)) and remove handler (only manually).

Comment: OP ninja-edited _"I can't undo as I have done other changes before trying to fix this"_ in. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster ah those ninjas :)

Comment: This action undoes some additional changes that made before the method generation accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

[Winforms - Visually remove button click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751782/winforms-visually-remove-button-click-event)

This shows how to remove event handlers using Visual Studio 2012. F4 and under the properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the event method, build, and then remove all the other errors.